# Migrate projects between VSTS Accounts

Tags: migration, azure-devops

Is there any way to migrate whole projects between different VSTS Accounts?

We need to move/copy some projects from one to another VSTS Account including all artifacts, code, history, work items, build & release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No at present this is not possible.

The only option available is to do a replay-migration which essentially copies all data from one account to another. You will lose some data in the process (not everything can be easily copied) and some dates and user's names will be reset, as the date of the date of the copy will be used and the user performing the migration may end up as the user performing the action.

Tools like:

- [OpsHub Migrator](http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/)
- [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](http://nkdagility.com/vsts-sync-migration-tools/)

Can help, but none offer a full fidelity migrations. Each tool has its own limitations.

At the moment if you need to hand off a project to another organisation these are your only options.