# Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: export, azure-devops

Is it possible to export Visual Studio Team Services project to a local PC with full history? If not, can one project be transferred to a new Visual Studio Team Services? These two are completely separated.

Comment: What do you mean the full history in this case, did you mean each version of source code or all  artifacts like code, history info, work items, build & release.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Is it possible to export Visual Studio Team Services project to a local PC with full history?*

> You can use our tools in Visual Studio, Eclipse, or from the command
>   line to keep a local copy of your source code on your machine. Today
>   there isn’t a way to export work items or other project data to your
>   local machine, but we’re planning on adding this capability at a later
>   date.

2. *Can one project be transferred to a new Visual Studio Team Services?*

> It's also not possible at present.
>
> The only option available is to do a replay-migration which
>   essentially copies all data from one account to another. You could use
>   some 3-party tools to handle this. Details please refer
>   *jessehouwing*'s answer in this similar question: [Migrate projects between VSTS Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156880/migrate-projects-between-vsts-accounts)

Comment: Re Point 1) with Eclipse, are we able to get the full history from VSTS?

Comment: @TimHo Do you mean each version of source code, If so, you could use Team Explorer Everywhere which an open-source Eclipse plug-in to connect Eclipse to VSTS, with the help of the TEE, it's just like use source control explorer in VS, you could either get the latest version in server to local or select a specific changeset with source code for history version. There is no way to simply pull all versions with full history for all files in local at once. But you are able to select the versions as your need.